# FindFirstFile cout problems

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to find files with certain extentions, for example *.doc, *.docx
First, i'm looking for all files

```
lstrcat(szPath, L"*");
hFind = FindFirstFile(szPath, &fdFindData);
```

Then, i compare founded file with extention i need

```
PCWSTR str1 = L".doc";

if(NULL != StrStr(fdFindData.cFileName,str1)) {
        FoundFileFunction(fdFindData.cFileName);
         }
```

And then I got problem with cout

```
VOID FoundFileFunction(HANDLE hFile)
{
    std::cout<<hFile;
}
```

This is output:

```
009AE50000
009AEB0000
009AEBBB00
```

and so on. What's the problem?

Comment: When i use"std::wcout" i got - 00ABECA4

Comment: What did you expect printing out a `HANDLE` to do? You need to tell us what you meant to do, since this code (by your own admission) does not do that thing.

Comment: The downvote is due to lack of research (see my answer).

Comment: Your test for file extensions is brittle, at best. It uses a **case-sensitive** compare, which is useless when operating on a case-insensitive filesystem. It also produces false positives, if the extension happens to appear anywhere inside the file name, e.g. `spin.doctors.mp3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`WIN32_FIND_DATA::cFileName` is a `TCHAR[MAX_PATH]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740(v=vs.85).aspx), not a `HANDLE`.
I don't know why you wrote `HANDLE`, as that's not uttered on the documentation page even once.

Your function is trying to print out the C-string filename as if it were a `HANDLE`, which is a different kind of pointer to a `TCHAR*`. It doesn't know to take the pointer as a `TCHAR*` so it doesn't know you want it to format the output as a string. It can only know to print the address represented by the pointer.

**Your function `FoundFileFunction` should take a `TCHAR*`.**

The problem would have been automatically detected had you used *STRICT* mode. If (for example) `NO_STRICT` is defined then `HANDLE` is an alias for `void*` which, per the rules of the language, can be initialised implicitly from a `TCHAR*`. You should always [compile with `STRICT` defined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383732.aspx): that would have changed the types not to be implicitly convertible to one another, and you would have received a compilation error for your mistake.

Furthermore, if your program is using Unicode, then `TCHAR` is not `char` but `wchar_t`, so you need to use not `std::cout` but `std::wcout`.

Comment: "I'm surprised that this compiles" - If `STRICT` is not defined, such as if `NO_STRICT` is defined, `HANDLE` is a typedef for `void*`, which would allow a `TCHAR[]`/`TCHAR*` to be passed where a `HANDLE` is expected.  You should always compile with `STRICT` defined to catch coding errors like this. See [STRICT Type Checking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383732.aspx).